# Migration error in django models.py database

Tags: python, django

My app is installed correctly and its models.py reads:

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_lenght=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_lenght=1000)

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
```

But whenever I run python manage.py migrate, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\dougl\desktop\django websites\twenty_one_pilots\downloads\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Album(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\dougl\desktop\django websites\twenty_one_pilots\downloads\models.py", line 4, in Album
    artist = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
  File "C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1042, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

What could be wrong? I'm still a beginner and I'm still learning about databases.

Comment: lenght splelling is wrong

Comment: OMG! That's why copying and pasting code can be dangerous sometimes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

As per my comment, length (lenght) splelling is wrong.

```
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.TextField()

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled length wrong here

```
album_title = models.CharField(max_lenght=500)
```

happens to the best of us.